# Get both advantage of multline ( spacing) AND equation/multlined (numbering)

Tags: equations, mathtools, multline

I like the spacing of `multline` but not the numbering (on the last line).
I tought for a moment that `equation`+`multlined`  will do the trick but that is not the case right now. The numbering is OK, but the spacing is far more "centered" on the page and I did not manage to improve it in any way (`flushleft`/`flushright` did not work either).

Can anyone help me?

MWE: 
Compare

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
111111111+2222222222\\3333333333333+4444444444\\=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{multline}

\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
111111111+2222222222\\3333333333333+4444444444\\=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get (almost) the same behavior with `multlined` if you tell it the width you want it to use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
111111111+2222222222\\3333333333333+4444444444\\=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{multline}

\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}[c][.9\displaywidth]
111111111+2222222222\\3333333333333+4444444444\\=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The first optional argument tells the alignment with respect to the context, the second is the width. Don't use the whole width, because you have to accommodate the equation number.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to set the width globally?

Comment: @MarcoVenuti Perhaps, but why? Different displays usually require different adjustments.

Comment: @MarcoVenuti Anyway, I checked and there's no way to do it, else than redefining an internal command. You can define your own `mvmultlined` environment, though, say `\NewDocumentEnvironment{mvmultlined}{O{c}ob}{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\begin{multlined}[#1][0.9\displaywidth]}{\begin{multlined}[#1}[#2]}#3\end{multlined}}{}`